# Find the index of the previous row in a table in Matlab

Tags: matlab

If I have the following table in Matlab:

```
T = table(['KAT';'MAT';'PAT';'SAT';'RAT'],[38;43;38;40;49],[71;69;64;67;64],[176;163;131;133;119])


T =

  5×4 table

    Var1    Var2    Var3    Var4
    ____    ____    ____    ____

    KAT      38      71     176 
    MAT      43      69     163 
    PAT      38      64     131 
    SAT      40      67     133 
    RAT      49      64     119
```

How do i refer to the entire row above PAT.

For example, the below code finds the row matching to PAT

```
>> T((ismember(T.Var1,'PAT','rows')),:)

ans =

  1×4 table

    Var1    Var2    Var3    Var4
    ____    ____    ____    ____

    PAT      38      64     131
```

But when I  deduct 1 in the index to find the row above the matched row for 'PAT' , i get the following error :

```
>> T((ismember(T.Var1,'PAT','rows')-1),:)
Index in position 1 is invalid. Array
indices must be positive integers or logical
values.
```

Is there any way i could find the row above to the row that matched for 'PAT' ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output from your `ismember` is a vector `[0 0 1 0 0]'`.  If you subtract one from that you get `[-1 -1 0 -1 -1]'` which isn't a valid index.  A simple solution is to use `find` and then subtract 1.

```
T((find(ismember(T.Var1, 'PAT', 'rows'))-1), :)

ans = 

    Var1    Var2    Var3    Var4

    ____    ____    ____    ____

    MAT     43      69      163
```

`find` returns the indices of non-zero elements.

Another option is to use `circshift` to move elements in the vector.

```
T(circshift(ismember(T.Var1, 'PAT', 'rows'),-1), :)

ans = 

    Var1    Var2    Var3    Var4
    ____    ____    ____    ____

    MAT     43      69      163
```